# Is there a way to automate an AirDrop between computers?

Tags: airdrop

I'm currently playing around with different Mac processes and I had the idea to be able to send an AirDrop using an automated program, say, when a task is completed. No particular language.

I have scoured the internet and cannot seem to find any information on whether or not this is possible and, if it is, how it can be done.

If anyone knows and would be happy to share, I would be greatly appreciative.

Thanks!